# unique value from each bucket in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a sample database of 1000 bank accounts.

```
{"account_number":1,"balance":39225,...,"state":"IL"}
```

What I want is list of highest balance accounts in each state. Using a terms aggregator I received collected count of accounts from each state.
eg.

```
"aggregations" : {
    "states" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "tx",
        "doc_count" : 30
      }, ....
```

But this doesn't returns the required list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use max aggregation

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "max_price" : { "max" : { "field" : "price" } }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html

Comment: nesting this aggregator inside terms aggregator would work. But that would only give me list of highest bank balances not highest balance accounts.

What is missing is remaining details associated with highest balance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at significant terms aggregation http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html - this generates buckets with related terms. Explore it